# I am trying to filter search a table that is paginated

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

It only retrieves data that is on the current page, not all the data in the database.How do i get it to filter through all the records and not only the records on the current page.I am using laravel for my backend and javascript for the filter search function.I have 10 records my table paginates at 5 records.I can filter search 5 records but not the entire 10.The rest of the records i can only filter when go to the second page

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-0">
            <div class="panel panel-default">

              <div class="form-group">

                <div class="panel-heading">Admin Dashboard <a href ="/users/index" style="margin-left:50px">USERS</a></div>
              <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">


              <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (session('message'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session('message') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                @if ($orders->count() == 0)
                    <p>No orders yet.</p>


                @else

                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="myTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th >Customer Name</th>
                                    <th>Address</th>
                                    <th>Phone</th>
                                    <th>Delivery date</th>
                                    <th>Type</th>
                                    <th>Flavor</th>
                                    <th>Frosting</th>
                                    <th>How many</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                    <th>Instructions</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach ($orders as $order)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ $order->id }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $order->customer->name }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $order->address }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $order->phone }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $order->delivery }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $order->size }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $order->flavor }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $order->toppings }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $order->number }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $order->price }}</td>
                                        <td style="max-width:200px"><textarea>{{ $order->instructions }}</textarea></td>
                                        <td><a href="{{ route('admin.orders.edit', $order) }}">{{ $order->status->name }}</a></td>
                                        <td><a href="{{ route('admin.orders.destroy', $order) }}"> <button class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm" >Delete</button></a></td>

                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>

                        </table>

                    </div> <!-- end table-responsive -->

                @endif
              <div id="links">  {{$orders->links()}}</div>



                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td,links, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  links=document.getElementById("links");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Because you're paginating in PHP before this view is loaded, then your Javascript is filtering those results.   You haven't tried to load any additional results...

Comment: You won't be able to filter via javascript unless you pass all the records to the page. You'd be better off handing the query to a controller and using the query builder to filter the records before paginating. Or switching your pagination to use Ajax.

Comment: It's worth looking into [data tables](https://www.datatables.net/) and the [data tables laravel library](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables)

Comment: @apokryfos thank you...data tables worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can't filter data the is not fetched from the beckend without making another API call.
You can either make another API call with the filter (and the pagenate the answer), or retrieve all the data from the server and make the pagination only for display porposes (not recommended at all)

Answer (score 0):

POST your Javascript Filter to a Controller which stores it in Session, in your loadingController retrieve that Session Variable and filter before paginate